# Should I avoid modifying user inputs before sending to backend if possible?

Tags: request, parameter-passing, frontend, user-input

I'm validating and sanitizing user inputs from the server-side. I'm also validating it from the front-end. But I'm wondering if I should also modify the input values to match the server's requirement before sending a request.

For example, I have a form with a birthday text input in `MM-dd` format. But the server requires a month(`MM`) and a day of the month(`dd`) values separately. I can format the input to match the server's requirement(`MM` and `dd`), or I can just pass the value without modification and the server will do the rest. Which method is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

This question is more related to UX practices then frontend itself. I believe that before server validation, frontend checks should be performed.

You shouldn't validate and you definitely shouldn't change any values during user completing the form. However the common practice is to validate fields on blur. This is when you can change fields values. 
However I would be very careful with this, to avoid confusing the user. So stripping whitespaces etc. should not be a problem, but aggressive input changes should be avoided.

Also try input masking for operations like date formats.

Check for example this library
https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

**EDIT:**

I case of changing values before sending them to backend, it's perfectly fine. It's good practice to have some mapping layer, which will map between UI forms and DTOs required by backend. UI should be focused on user experience, so some extra work will be required almost every time in more complex scenarios

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I was saying `modification`, I meant refining request parameter values in the javascript before sending requests. Not changing input values directly.

Comment: Mapping data from UI to some DTO required by server is perfectly fine. These are two separate layers, while UI should be best user friendly, so we can't expect the data to be exactly the same.